# Java Can't delete image file, itext7 html To Pdf conversion image file lock after writing to PDF

Tags: java, tomcat, delete-file, itext7, html-to-pdf

I am creating a multi page PDF file from HTML templates. There are some images as well that I'm showing in PDF. PDF generate successfully and images are added in PDF file.
But After this when I want to delete images they are not deleting, Popup appears that files are locked.
When I kill the program that writes PDF file, then you can delete images.

```
public void createPdf(String htmlString) throws IOException {
     PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\filename.pdf");
     PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

     ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
     HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, pdf, properties);

     pdf.close();
     writer.close();
}
```

**Note**

1. I am converting HTML **text** to pdf.
2. In html text *img* tag is used to insert external images from local file system.

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Comment: Added sample code

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is a bug in iText7. It has been fixed already and the fix will be available in `7.1.2` release (and correspondingly pdfHTML 2.0.2).

If you want to use the fixed version already, you can build iText Core from sources yourself. The commit fixing the issue is [4565db5de87666dc60d65befb463a0519fb8334d](https://github.com/itext/itext7/commit/4565db5de87666dc60d65befb463a0519fb8334d). You don't have to build custom pdfHTML version because fix was only in iText7 Core.

Build instructions are available [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/BUILDING.md).

Comment: When is 7.1.2 planned to be released?

Comment: @Adnan what exactly do you want me to check? Your notes don't change anything.